# How to get the scrolltoposition end event in android

Tags: java, android

i'm developing an android application and i'm switching between multiple fragments with single instances.
in one of these fragments i have a long list of images which only one item is visible at a time(i have used pagerSnapHelper class if that can be of use).
what i'm trying to achieve is when an item on another fragment is clicked i want to switch to this imagesListFragment and scroll to the corresponding position. However, for the sake of better animation performance i'm trying to run the switching sequentially. right now what i have implemented is switching to the fragment and then calling scrollToPosition on the recyclerView, but it would be more convenient to first scroll to the item and then switch to the fragment( This way the scrolling part is not visible to the user). Unfortunately, i have not been able to find any events to monitor the scrollToPosition Method getting finished.are there any eventHandlers that can help me achieve this kind of behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)

this might help after setting the adapter set linerlayoutmanager's position to ur position with `0` offset

Comment: @Anmol  i know about the scrolling functionality. what i seek is a way to run the fragment switching as soon as the scrolToPosition has finished